# Does this code make sense? C++ copy return vs ptr in

Tags: c++, c++17

Which version of this code is better (or is there an even better way to do it)?

Copy out

```
void TranslatMat(float x, float y, float z) {
    Matrix matTranslation = {
       1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, x,
       0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, y,
       0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, z,
       0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    return matTransltion;
}
```

OR Ptr in

```
void rlTranslateMat(float x, float y, float z, Matrix *result) {
  *result = {
       1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, x,
       0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, y,
       0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, z,
       0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }; 
}
```

I just learned the rule of fifths and move constructors. Does that even apply here?

I know a 4x4 Matrix struct isn't huge but I plan to use this function every frame and this pattern for larger structs than a matrix.

Comment: Your first example "copy out" won't compile. It is declared as a `void` function but returns a value.

Comment: Begin by defining "better". What do you want to optimize for? Memory usage? Speed? Readability? Something else?

Comment: *Witch version of this code is better*  -- First, write the code without any usage of pointers.  Use pointers when you must use them.  Also, overly using pointers when you don't need to can and will render the compiler optimizations lessened or even not doable due to pointer aliasing (in other words, slowing your code down, not speeding it up).  Those "pointer tricks" may have worked back in the 80's and 90's, but today's compiler optimization techniques renders those tricks useless.

Comment: The first one should be written as `return Matrix{/*...*/};` or, assuming the return type on the function is already declared as `Matrix`, alternatively `return {/*...*/};`. Not using an intermediate variable doesn't change the meaning of the code except that it guarantees copy elision since C++17. (Minor exceptions apply since `= {/*...*/}` doesn't 100% do the same, but there should be no difference for a reasonably behaved class.)

Comment: To PaulMcKenzie's point above: return by value here will almost certainly trigger NRVO (the copy elision would even be guaranteed in C++17 or above if you got rid of the unnecessary function-local temporary variable), so no copies will be made at all.  A pointer to an out parameter will likely require your result matrix to first be default-initialized and then copy-assigned to, which could easily end up being slower (though it remains to be seen if the performance difference would matter).

Answer (score 3):

```
Matrix TranslatMat(float x, float y, float z) {
```

gives the most readable calling code

```
auto M = TranslatMat( x, y, z );
```

This will save you hours of work debugging your application

Once your application is working, then you can think about optimizing, but only code where time profiling shows it will make a significant improvement - likely not this code.

Answer (score 1):

The first example you are making a local matrix and then 'returning by value'. However, you have defined it as 'void'. This means you won't be able to return anything. If you attempted to compile the first example it will fail. to fix it you need to change type 'void' to type 'Matrix'

The second example you are passing a pointer to the function, directly modifying said data, then should return void (nothing).

There is no best case and to know which one to use.

- If you are looking for a function to generate a matrix and you start working with it, lean towards the first example.
- If you have an existing matrix and want to modify it, then you can use the second example.

However, given that this is c++, you could also choose to pass by reference.

Given the nature of this question, I would recommend you to read up on: pass by value, pass by reference, and pass by pointer.

Afterwards, look into learning more about return types as well as dynamically allocated memory.

Once all of these are understood, then go back to the rule of 3 or 5 and move/copy constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Returning the matrix will be better because:

1. it's more readable
2. it allows copy elision
3. it avoids potential aliasing with other `Matrix *` or `float *`

The last too will result in faster code.

Note: the compiler will turn it into *ptr in* if it can't optimize it, except it will use the structure return register instead of the 4th argument register.